# Cannot import table due to zombie constraint

Tags: mariadb, foreign-key, constraint, mariadb-10.1

I tried to refresh my copy of the production database by emptying and importing a SQL file. I've done it hundreds of times, only this time the import failed.

I tried dropping & recreating the database, and got the same error. I tried deleting the constraints from the SQL file before importing it, and got the same error. I tried creating the table in PHPMyAdmin, with the same table-schema, and got the same error. Ditto when I tried creating a table with a different table-schema. I tried importing the file to a new database -- which worked -- but got the same error when I tried to copy the tables to the old database.

How can I delete these constraints? How can I check for more deleted-but-still-effective constraints? How should I avoid this in future?

MySQL (commandline 'mysql') returns this:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 744: Can't create table `<database>`.`<table>` (errno: -1 "Internal error < 0 (Not system error)")
```

The error log is more helpful; note <link-table> has/had the constraints:

```
InnoDB: Error: cannot load foreign constraint <database>/<link-table>_ibfk_1: could not find the relevant record in SYS_FOREIGN
```

When I import the file as , the error becomes this:

```
InnoDB: Error: cannot load foreign constraint <database>/<table>_ibfk_1: found <database2>/<link-table>_ibfk_1 instead in SYS_FOREIGN
```

I'm running Debian Stable, with MariaDB 10.1.37

Comment: It'd be helpful if the downvoters would give a reason

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a 'proper' answer to my question, but did find a workaround: deleting the idb* files. I used this script to do it: https://github.com/uberhacker/shrink-ibdata1.